# How to get sum slalry year by year using SQL query?

Tags: mysql

MySQL table **slalry**:

```
aid    year    slalry
1      2000    1000
2      2001    2000
3      2002    3000
4      2003    4000
```

### How to get result as :

```
aid    year    slalry
1      2000    1000
2      2001    3000
3      2002    6000
4      2003    10000
```

Comment: Is "slalry" supposed to mean "salary"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sql code:

```
   SELECT
        aid,year,
        salary=(SELECT SUM(slalry) FROM slalry WHERE year<=A.year)
    FROM slalry AS A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get exactly the result you specify, as there will be no unique [aid] value for each year. However, omitting this column, you can use:

```
SELECT  year, SUM(slalry)
FROM    slalry
GROUP BY year
```